# Javascript swap characters in string

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have a string like `"abcabcabc"` and I want the positions of 'a's and 'b's swapped so that I end up with `"bacbacbac"`. What is the most elegant solution for this? (For the sake of this question I hereby define 'elegant' as fast and readable.)

I came up with

```
"abcabcabc".replace( /[ab]/g, function( c ){ return { 'a': 'b', 'b': 'a' }[ c ] } )
```

Which I neither regard fast nor readable. But now I wonder if there is a better way of doing it?

EDIT: The characters can be at any position. So the answer should hold for "xyza123buvwa456" (would be then "xyzb123auvwb456", too.

EDIT2: "swap" seems to be the wrong word. Replace all of a with b and all of b with a while both are single characters.

---

I throw in a couple of other ones:

```
"abcabcabc".replace( 'a', '_' ).replace( 'b','a' ).replace( '_', 'b' )

"abcabcabc".replace( /[ab]/g, function( c ){ return "ba".charAt( c.charCodeAt()-'a'.charCodeAt() ); } )

"abcabcabc".replace( /[ab]/g, function( c ){ return "ab".charAt( "ba".indexOf( c ) ) } )
```

I ended up using a modified version of Mark C.'s Answer:

```
"abcabcabc".replace( /[ab]/g, c => c == 'a' ? 'b' : 'a' )
```

Comment: So, how are you measuring performance that that code isn't fast? We need an object way to measure the answers or this is going to be opinion-based...

Comment: So this looks more like you are just replacing `a` with `b` and `b` with `a` rather than swapping. Is that actually intentional, because it's not quite the same thing. For example `aaab` -> `bbba` if you just replace, whereas if you swap you might expect `baaa` (or `aaba` your rules on swapping aren't clear here)

Comment: [How do I swap substrings within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7151466/215552)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I swap substrings within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151466/how-do-i-swap-substrings-within-a-string)

Comment: @Matt: You are right. See Edit2.

Comment: Mike/Mark: There is a significant difference between replacing single chars and whole strings. See my own edits/examples why this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this :

```
str.replace(/[ab]/g, function($1) { return $1 === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a' })
```

example:

```js
console.log("abcabcabc".replace(/[ab]/g, function($1) { return $1 === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a' }))
```

Comment: You don't need the pipe `|`. In fact, it shouldn't be there at all

Comment: @MattBurland Got it - I was trying a myriad of different combinations and TBH have been trying to learn RegEx throug SO. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with a slightly modified version but I think this is both the cleanest and fastest way of doing it. (At least if not someone finds a sane way of doing it without regex.)

Answer (score 4):

You can swap them (if they're always adjacent) by using a `split`/`join` combo:

```js
console.log("abcabcabc".split("ab").join("ba"))
```

And in keeping with the split/join method, here's a way to swap them as individual characters (although it becomes significantly less readable):

```js
console.log("aabbccaabbcc".split("a").map(s => s.split("b").join("a")).join("b"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really like it's creative approach. But please see Edit.

Comment: @Scheintod I edited the answer with a way to swap non-adjacent characters, although I don't know if I'd recommend ever doing it that way (a regex replace is almost certainly more readable).

Answer (score 1):

`replace` function accepts a string as the second parameter.

`"abcabcabc".replace( /ab/g, "ba")`

Comment: That will replace both `a` and `b` with `ba`

Answer (score 1):

I use this [method](https://straighttips.blogspot.com/2018/11/javascript-string-swap-no-delimiter.html) when I need to swap long list of characters\words\strings!

The method also prevents strings already replaced to be replaced again, Example:

```
String = "AAABBBCCC BBB"

Replace "AAABBBCCC" with "BBB", then, "BBB" with "DDD"

Final String = "BBB DDD"
```

Note that, only "BBB" from the original string is replaced to "DDD"! The "BBB" replaced from "AAABBBCCC" is not re-replaced to "DDD"!

Answer (score 0):

**Use a direct replace using Regex:**

```js
var result = "abcabcabc".replace( /ab/g, "ba");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @MarkC. are you serius?  I was writing the answer using the JS snippet tool [<>]

Comment: @MarkC. you're wrong, he posted a wrong answer and then modified it

Comment: @MarkC. look the versions of his answer, come on!