# How to swap two adjacent characters in a string variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, swap

let string = 'abcdefghij';
the result I want string = 'abdcefhgij'.
The changes should be made are cd to dc and gh to hg rest of the string is unaltered.

Comment: Use regex replace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript swap characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571430/javascript-swap-characters-in-string)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Michal, could you please write it for me ?

Comment: @IvicaPesovski It worked, but how to shortened that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in one go, create a function that will map each characters you want to swap, like this:

```
function charReplace(char) {
    if(char == 'c') return 'd';
    if(char == 'd') return 'c';
    if(char == 'g') return 'h';
    if(char == 'h') return 'g';
}
```

Then you can pass this function as the second parameter to the `replace` function like this:

```
const originalString = 'abcdefghij';
const replacedString = originalString.replace(/[cdgh]/g, ($1) => charReplace($1));
```

If you need to map more chars, just add `if` blocks in the `charReplace` function. If it gets too long, you can implement it by keeping the map into an array and returning the element at the correct index.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Ivica !! You made it simpler !!

Comment: @PVD mark the answer as accepted please if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const string1 = 'abcdefghij'.replace(/[cd]/g, (c) => (c == 'c' ? 'd' : 'c'));
    console.log(string1);
    const string2 = string1.replace(/[gh]/g, (c) => (c == 'g' ? 'h' : 'g'));
    console.log(string2);
```

I did this. finally got the result in the form of string2. Anyone could suggest how to do it in one go?